# Basic CakePHP: Unable to get the id (Edit Method)

Tags: cakephp, sql-update

This my database:
http://gyazo.com/c6a86127d6f91aae947cf45ee535cecd

Example:
http://gyazo.com/c23fec3fabb7e4504c42453980fbc372
When I press the edit button , they able to retrieve the data however the page show me empty field instead of the field that have old data.

Secondly, unable to undate because they keep send empty id_field back to controller.

p.s. add,edit,delete method work totally fine.

Below are my code:
**Model**

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');

class EventDate extends AppModel {
     public $useTable = 'eventdate';
     public $primaryKey = 'eventDate_id';

     public $validate = array(
       'event_date'  => array(
           'rule' => array('date','ymd'),
           'message' => 'Enter a valid date in YY-MM-DD format.',
           'required' => true,
           'allowEmpty' => false
       )
     );


}
```

**Controller**

```
 public function edit($id = null) {
    //Retrieve from database
    $post = $this->EventDate->findByEventdateId($id);
    $this->set('edate', $post)  ;

//    debug($post);    

    //Without Id
    if (!$id) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid Event Date'));
    }

    //If  Not Exist the id
    if (!$post) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid Event Date'));
    }

    //After press the submit
    if ($this->request->is(array('post','put'))) {
        $this->EventDate->eventDate_id = $id;
        debug($_POST);

        if ($this->EventDate->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The Event has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));}

        else
            {$this->Session->setFlash(__('The Event could not be saved. Please, try again.'));}
    }

    //Set the data same as retrieved
    if (!$this->request->data) { $this->request->data = $post;}
}
```

**edit.ctp**

```
   <h2>Edit Event</h2>

<?php
echo $this->Form->create('eventdate');
//echo $this->Form->input('eventDate_id', array('type' => 'hidden'));

echo $this->Form->hidden('eventDate_id');
echo $this->Form->input('event_date',array(
    'label' => 'Event Date',
    'type' => 'text',
    'id' => 'datepicker'));
echo $this->Form->end('Save Post');
?>
```

---

Below link is the debug($_Post) been shown:
http://gyazo.com/5e569e6cc6b3026fc8896c315197a938

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be:

```
echo $this->Form->create('EventDate');  // notice the capital CamelCase
```

**Side note:**  The info that displays in the fields will be out-of-date, since you 1) get the data from the DB and set to var, THEN do the save based on posted data.

**Another side note:**  There are quite a few things that you're doing that are non-standard and not consistent w/ the recommended conventions.  Cleaning that up will make it easier to work with AND easier to receive help.

Comment: Thank for helped me to solve the problem.
I have read the "cakephp-conventions." however I still got some confusion , can you help state some of the non-standard conventions of my work ?
I will try to take note of that and do some changes.

Comment: Bake ("cake bake") your code, this way you see how it's done.

Comment: Bake ("cake bake") ? I still confuse what you mean.

Comment: @beginnerK - just follow the very in-depth tutorials in the CakePHP book online.   After doing that, you'll have a much better idea of what we're referring to.  Also, if this answer solved your problem, please mark it as the answer so more people don't waste time thinking this is unanswered.